# Converting int to char with unknown int size

Tags: c, char

I'm using the following functions :

```
hourFormat12() returns -> 1-12
minute() returns -> 1-60
```

How do I convert these integers into chars without knowing if the int is one or two digits?

I'm used to Java and Strings and I could typically do this when initializing a String :

```
String myString = "12" + ":" + "30" + "AM";
```

How can this be accomplished with a char array, without knowing the size of each of the strings.

Comment: "How do I convert these integers into chars without knowing if the int is one or two digits?": `sprintf(newstring, "%d", intvar)`?

Comment: One way: `sprintf(buffer, "%d:%02d AM", hour, minute);`  This uses 1 or 2 digits for the hour, but always 2 digits for the minute.  The `%02d` format will prepend a `0` if the minute is only one digit.

Comment: sprintf(buffer, "%d:%02d AM", hour, minute); works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Typical C way is to determine the maximum size that your output can be and use that as the size of your char array. There are macros in `<limits.h>` if you want to be 100% portable. Don't forget the null terminator!

Answer (score 1):

You create a char array large enough to accomodate the data after inspecting it.

In this case, since the maximum required size of the array would be 8 chars (including null terminator) you can simply not bother with this and use a fixed size of 8.

Comment: Thank you, but when I have a char array I can't use the + operator to add strings of text together? Like char* test[8] = "Test1" + "Test2";

Comment: C doesn't recognize `+` on string literals.  This is where you need to use @Evert's comment.

Comment: @Degustaf: C doesn't allow `+` with two string literal operands. It *does* allow `+` with a string literal and an integer -- but it performs pointer addition, not string concatenation. For example, `printf("%s\n", "Hello" + 3);` prints `lo`. (I mention this because someone accustomed to Java might want to avoid doing this accidentally.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Thanks, I did not know that.  But, that is certainly not what OP is interested in.

Comment: @JackTrowbridge: No, you can never do that with "strings" in C. You just copy stuff into the array manually at the correct position. Also be always careful with the extra char required for the null terminator -- your example code would try to stuff 9 characters in a size 8 buffer even if it worked.

Comment: Thank you all, Yeah I understand now, it was what I originally thought but I needed a way to add strings/ints together and place them into a char array. sprintf() does that job perfectly!